# how i can fix this error? AbstractController::DoubleRenderError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redmine, python-redmine

I want to recover data in two different tables and put the data on excel but I have a little bug if someone has an idea. Thank you

```
class ExportController < ApplicationController

def index
@attachments= Attachment.all
@projects= Project.all
 respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.csv {send_data @attachments.to_csv}
  format.xls {send_data @attachments.to_csv(col_sep: "\t") and send_data @projects.to_csv(col_sep: "\t")}

end

end 
end
```

route.rb

```
get '/export', to: 'export#index'
```

model..

```
class Export < ActiveRecord::Base

   def self.to_csv(options = {})
      CSV.generate(options) do |csv|
      csv << column_names
      all.each do |table|
      csv << table.attributes.values_at(*column_names)
      end
    end
  end

  end
```

view

```
<h1>Exportation</h1>
<%= link_to 'Download as .xlsx', export_path(format: :xls) %>
```

model (project.rb)

```
  class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
    def self.to_csv(options = {})
    CSV.generate(options) do |csv|
    csv << column_names
    all.each do |project|
   csv << project.attributes.values_at(*column_names)
  end
  end
 end
end
```

model (attachment.rb)

```
class Attachment < ActiveRecord::Base
 def self.to_csv(options = {})
      CSV.generate(options) do |csv|
      csv << column_names
      all.each do |table|
      csv << table.attributes.values_at(*column_names)
      end
    end
  end
  end
```

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7BRAY.png)

Comment: The error is because you call `send_data` twice in `format.xls` block.

Comment: I'm not sure if you can respond with more than one files in single request. You can try to do it in separate requests.

Comment: thank you but I want to recover everything at the same time and there I have no idea for now

Comment: Can you join the results together and then use send_data to render the result. In that case you will not call render multiple times in the controller and the action will work perfectly without error.

Comment: how please.I am beginner with rails

Comment: If you need to send several files at once, you can always zip them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't respond twice one request. An option would be:

```
format.xls {send_data @attachments.to_csv(col_sep: "\t") + @projects.to_csv(col_sep: "\t") }
```

With this, you'll respond with one file containing attachments and projects.

Comment: thank you it works but it puts it in the same excel sheet and it's not organized is it possible to separate (the data) of different sheets

Comment: @mordiop: what sheets? You're rendering a text file (csv). To get proper sheets, you need to learn to render an .xlsx file. I like gem `axlsx` for these tasks.

Comment: That's what is troubling me. @mordiop you have a `format.csv` to handle csv request, but in `format.xls` too, you are rendering a csv.